# Install vcpkg with visual studio 13 ultimate

Tags: windows, visual-studio, vcpkg

I want to install **cpprestsdk** library on windows, which require **vcpkg**.

To install vcpkg we require Visual Studio 15+. I am using VS13 Ultimate, so is there a way to install vcpkg without having VS15 ?